# Rachet and named pipes in linux

Tags: php, named-pipes, ratchet

I am using Rachet to create sockets, one of the update methods is something being written to a named pipe (`mkfifo filename`)

The code below works

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
$application = new WebSocketApplication(),
8080
);
$updateFile = fopen('/tmp/testing', 'r');

$update = function ($stream) use ($application, $server, $u) {
    $value = fread($stream, 8219);
    $application->update($value);
    //the line below is magic apparently, if this is removed, I end up in an infinite loop
    fopen('/tmp/testing', 'r');
};
$server->loop->addReadStream($updateFile, $update);

$server->run();
```

That works completely as expected. I have no idea why I need the second fopen line.

Can someone explain why its needed or what I am doing wrong to even need this line.

Comment: A general hint: If reading from a stream, assume always, the the input is incomplete or covers parts of 2 records. There is no guarantee the a record is read as once or that a read operation ends at record end: Streams (except SOCK_SEQPACKET for unix sockets) don't know anything about records.

Comment: @wiimm I have done, that doesnt help here, this is a basic case